# How to detect if the outbound call has been forwarded?

Tags: twilio

When making an outbound phone call and if the call has been forwarded to another phone number, Is there a way to retrieve the forwarded-to phone number?  Or is there a way to detect if the outbound call has been forwarded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Unfortunately thats not something that is possible for us to know on our end, so there isn't a way for us to give it to you.

Hope that helps.